# Any available reporting tool for Behat/Mink?

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

Is there any **available tools to analyse the output of the functionnal tests** i launched with Behat/Mink ?

Something like :

- how many times i launched this scenario
- how many times it failed
- how many times it passed
- maybe even show warning when a scenario has not been tested since X days

Actualy after each test, the output is pretty cool, but it would be even nicer if we can *store* some statistics after each tests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest thing I can think of is generating Behat reports with jUnit format, and feed your CI.

Jenkins-CI is able to generate statistics using these reports. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin